# Browserify @google/earthengine

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-earth-engine, outsystems

I'm trying to browserify google earth engine Javascript API.

I installed the module:

```
npm install --save-dev @google/earthengine
```

I created a new main.js file for testing purposes:

```
var md = require('@google/earthengine');
 
module.exports = MDOutSystems;

function MDOutSystems() {
  this.mdInstance = md;
};

MDOutSystems.prototype.data.authenticateViaPrivateKey = function(
    privateKey, opt_success, opt_error, opt_extraScopes,
    opt_suppressDefaultScopes) {
    md.data.authenticateViaPrivateKey(privateKey, opt_success, opt_error, opt_extraScopes,
        opt_suppressDefaultScopes);
};

MDOutSystems.prototype.initialize = function() {
    md.initialize();
};

MDOutSystems.prototype.Image = function(source) {
    md.Image(source);
};

MDOutSystems.prototype.getInstance = function () {
    return this.mdInstance;
}
```

(I've got an warning that I need to create a d.ts file with `declare module '@google/earthengine'` )

I used the following code to expose the module I created:

```
Browserify main.js --standalone MDOutSystems > google-earth-outsystems.js
```

Although, when I try to call

```
var ee = new MDOutSystems();
```

I got an error saying that "MDOutSystems is not defined".

Please, help.

I've tried moving the main.js to insie the folder /node_modules and run the browserify command again. It actually resulted in a totaly different google-earth-outsystems.js file but it still didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess Browserify minifies the code and changes function names.

`MDOutSystems()` is unknown afterwards.

Attach your method to the `window` object.

Like this:

```
function MDOutSystems() {
  this.mdInstance = md;
};

window.MDOutSystems = MDOutSystems;
```